# Unable to open Xamarin Studio on Windows 10

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio

I Have been follow the steps in this video to install xamarin studio without visual studio

[How to install Xamarin Studio in windows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FGYTrTz_Fgg)

and when i try to open it its not working,no message no anything

I try to run it as administrator and its doesnt work

Comment: Does anything happen?

Comment: Any errors in the IDE log? `%AppData%\Local\XamarinStudio-6.0\Logs`. Startup problems are usually down to a problem with GTK# and older versions, such as GTK# 2.12.30, have fixed the startup problem on Windows 10 for others. However this is a guess since the real problem should be in the IDE log file.

Comment: yes i found the log how i upload it?

Comment: @MattWard https://github.com/hemaezzat/stackoverflow/blob/master/Ide.2016-09-29__14-45-40.log

Comment: Yeah that looks like a gtk# problem. Can you try stopping Xamarin Studio, uninstalling GTK# and installing the older version - http://download.xamarin.com/GTKforWindows/Windows/gtk-sharp-2.12.30.msi

Comment: its work thanks man set it as answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look in the IDE log file, which is in the `%AppData%\Local\Xamarin-Studio-6.0\Logs` directory and you see an error similar to:

```
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'libglib-2.0-0.dll': The specified module could not be found.
```

Then you may be able to fix this by installing an older version of GTK#. Full steps to do this are:

1. Stop Xamarin Studio.
2. Uninstall GTK#.
3. Install an older version of GTK# such as [GTK# 2.12.30](http://download.xamarin.com/GTKforWindows/Windows/gtk-sharp-2.12.30.msi)

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin Studio on Windows 10 requires a bit of modification since we do not ship it in our Windows installer anymore:

https://www.xamarin.com/faq#xpq6

It is highly recommended to use Visual Studio on Windows as it is free with the Community Edition.

Comment: but there a people who use xamarin in windows without visual studio i want to test xamarin