# How do I get the option to create an Android solution in Xamarin Studio?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I have been install xamarin studio on Windows 10 today without visual studio but i cant found option creating Android solution

[solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsIyg.png)

Whan i try to update xamarin form there

[update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJDEo.png)

in this time i was have option to update xamarin to veroisn 6.0 but when i update it the program has been borken a lot of error in design and the UI of program and i uninstall it and reinstall it again but in this time i was have option to create android but i cant desgin it...

Thanks for helping

Comment: Xamarin Studio is no longer supported on Windows.  Use VS Community instead.

Comment: Duplicate Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39749547/unable-to-open-xamarin-studio-on-windows-10/39751037

Comment: i Want test xamarin on windows i dont want visual studio

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that you are using Xamarin Studio on Windows, you should really consider using Visual Studio on Windows:

https://www.xamarin.com/faq#xpq6

Not only does it have a more integrated feature set, but it is no longer included in our installer.